# ionic option select not working in 2nd level

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

My json

```
{
"product_id": "50",
"thumb": "",
"name": "AASHIRVAAD ATTA",
"price": "Rs.170.00",
"price_only": "170.0000",
"special": "Rs.160.00",
"minimum": "2",
"minimum_app_qty": 1,
"product_unit": "kg",
"qty": "10000",
"weight": 5,
"options": [{
    "product_id": "50",
    "product_option_id": "228",
    "option_id": "13",
    "product_option_value": [{
        "name": "10kg",
        "image": null,
        "price": "Rs.340.00",
        "price_only": 340
    }, {
        "name": "2kg",
        "image": null,
        "price": "Rs.71.00",
        "price_only": 71
    }]
}]}
```

i want to add select option in ionic

productlist.html

```
     <select class="item item-input item-select item-balanced" style="padding: 4px 10px 4px 0; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 4px; width: 34%;height: 30px; float: left;" ng-show="item.options==''">
             <option value="{{item.weight}}{{item.product_unit}}" >{{item.weight}}{{item.product_unit}}</option>
        </select>

        <select class="item item-input item-select item-balanced" style="padding: 4px 10px 4px 0; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 4px; width: 34%;height: 30px; float: left;" ng-repeat="opt in item.options" ng-show="item.options!=''">
             <option ng-repeat="opvalue in opt.product_option_value" >{{opvalue.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

its working fine but i want to add ng-change event in select option and get selected value run time

i try following code but not working

```
 <select class="item item-input item-select item-balanced" 
                ng-if="item.options.product_option_value.length > 1" 
                ng-model="item.options.selectedItem"
                ng-options="opt.name for opt in item.options.product_option_value">
            </select>
```

Comment: Do you get any error message in the browser console? What's not working? Is the `selectedItem` not correct?

Comment: <!-- ngIf: item.options.product_option_value.length > 1 -->

Comment: first i try productlist.html as i mention two select option with ng-show="item.options==''" and ng-show="item.options!=''" condition its working but i can use ng-change event in it so i try other solution which one is my code but its not working

Comment: `item.options` is an array. That's why your `ng-if` is not working. `ng-if="item.options[0].product_option_value.length > 1"` should work.

Comment: Dear AWolf its work but no data come

Comment: <select class="item item-input item-select item-balanced" 
                    ng-if="item.options[0].product_option_value.length > 1" 
                    ng-model="item.options[0]"
                    ng-options="opt.name for opt in item.options[0].product_option_value">
                </select>  i try this option come but disappear onchange

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't fully understand it. With the first drop down you'd like to show the second one and in the second one you'd like to trigger a change event on selection change. Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115511/discussion-between-amisha-and-awolf).